# Minecraft query tools

Tags: php, networking, minecraft

This is my first major PHP project and I haven't gotten much feedback.  I wanted to learn how to use PHP and I wanted to learn about Minecraft's status protocol, so I did what was obvious at the time.

## File listing

The code is also [on GitHub](https://github.com/winny-/mcstat).

### mcstat.php

Contains class `MinecraftStatus` and is also a stand-alone CLI tool.

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

class MinecraftStatus {

    public $hostname;
    public $port;

    public $stats;

    function __construct($hostname, $port=25565)
    {
        $this->hostname = $hostname;
        $this->port = $port;
    }

    public function ping()
    {
        $newStats = $this->serverListPing($this->hostname, $this->port);
        $this->stats[microtime()] = array(
                                          'stats' => $newStats,
                                          'method' => 'Server List Ping',
                                          'hostname' => $this->hostname,
                                          'port' => $this->port
                                          );

        return $newStats;
    }

    public function query($fullQuery=true)
    {
        if ($fullQuery) {
            $newStats = $this->fullQuery($this->hostname, $this->port);
            $this->stats[microtime()] = array(
                                              'stats' => $newStats,
                                              'method' => 'Full Query',
                                              'hostname' => $this->hostname,
                                              'port' => $this->port
                                              );
        } else {
            $newStats = $this->basicQuery($this->hostname, $this->port);
            $this->stats[microtime()] = array(
                                              'stats' => $newStats,
                                              'method' => 'Basic Query',
                                              'hostname' => $this->hostname,
                                              'port' => $this->port
                                              );
        }

        return $newStats;
    }

    /*
      ================
      Server List Ping
      ================

      An example of how to get a Minecraft server status's using a "Server List Ping" packet.
      See details here: http://www.wiki.vg/Server_List_Ping
    */

    private function packString($string)
    {
        return pack('n', strlen($string)) . mb_convert_encoding($string, 'UCS-2BE');
    }

    // This is needed since UCS-2 text rendered as UTF-8 contains unnecessary null bytes
    // and could cause other components, especially string functions to blow up. Boom!
    private function decodeUCS2BE($string)
    {
        return mb_convert_encoding($string, 'UTF-8', 'UCS-2BE');
    }

    private function serverListPing($hostname, $port=25565)
    {
        // 1. pack data to send
        $request = pack('nc', 0xfe01, 0xfa) .
            $this->packString('MC|PingHost') .
            pack('nc', 7+2*strlen($hostname), 73) .
            $this->packString($hostname) .
            pack('N', 25565);

        // 2. open communication socket and make transaction
        $time = microtime(true);
        $fp = stream_socket_client('tcp://' . $hostname . ':' . $port);
        if (!$fp) {
            return false;
        }
        fwrite($fp, $request);
        $response = fread($fp, 2048);
        fclose($fp);
        $time = round((microtime(true)-$time)*1000);

        // 3. unpack data and return
        if (strpos($response, 0xFF) !== 0) {
            return false;
        }
        $response = substr($response, 3);
        $response = explode(pack('n', 0), $response);

        return array(
                     'player_count' => $this->decodeUCS2BE($response[4]),
                     'player_max' => $this->decodeUCS2BE($response[5]),
                     'motd' => $this->decodeUCS2BE($response[3]),
                     'server_version' => $this->decodeUCS2BE($response[2]),
                     'protocol_version' => $this->decodeUCS2BE($response[1]),
                     'latency' => $time
                     );
    }

    /*
      =====
      Query
      =====

      This section utilizes the UT3 Query protocol to query a Minecraft server.
      Read about it here: http://wiki.vg/Query
    */

    private function getStrings($fp, $count)
    {
        $nulsProcessed = 0;

        while ($nulsProcessed < $count) {
            while ($c != chr(0)) {
                $s .= $c;
                $c = fread($fp, 1);
            }

            $strings[] = $s;
            $nulsProcessed++;

            unset($c);
            unset($s);
        }

        return $strings;
    }

    private function makeSessionId()
    {
        return rand(1, 0xFFFFFFFF) & 0x0F0F0F0F;
    }

    // Verify packet type and ensure it references our session ID.
    private function validateQueryResponse($response, $responseType, $sessionId)
    {
        if (strpos($response, $responseType) !== 0 && (int)substr($response, 1, 4) === $sessionId) {
            error_log('Received invalid response "' . bin2hex($response) . '". Returning.');
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private function handleQueryHandshake($fp, $sessionId)
    {
        $handshakeRequest = pack('cccN', 0xFE, 0xFD, 9, $sessionId);

        fwrite($fp, $handshakeRequest);
        $handshakeResponse = fread($fp, 2048);

        if (!$this->validateQueryResponse($handshakeResponse, 9, $sessionId)) {
            return false;
        }

        $challengeToken = substr($handshakeResponse, 5, -1);

        return $challengeToken;
    }

    private function basicQuery($hostname, $port=25565)
    {
        $sessionId = $this->makeSessionId();

        $fp = stream_socket_client('udp://' . $hostname . ':' . $port);
        if (!$fp) {
            return false;
        }

        $time = microtime(true);

        $challengeToken = $this->handleQueryHandshake($fp, $sessionId);
        if (!$challengeToken) {
            fclose($fp);
            return false;
        }

        $time = round((microtime(true)-$time)*1000);


        $statRequest = pack('cccNN', 0xFE, 0xFD, 0, $sessionId, $challengeToken);
        fwrite($fp, $statRequest);
        $statResponseHeader = fread($fp, 5);

        if (!$this->validateQueryResponse($statResponseHeader, 0, $sessionId)) {
            fclose($fp);
            return false;
        }

        $statData = array_merge($this->getStrings($fp, 5), unpack('v', fread($fp, 2)), $this->getStrings($fp, 1));

        fclose($fp);
        return array(
                     'motd' => $statData[0],
                     'gametype' => $statData[1],
                     'map' => $statData[2],
                     'player_count' => $statData[3],
                     'player_max' => $statData[4],
                     'port' => (string)$statData[5],
                     'ip' => $statData[6],
                     'latency' => $time
                     );
    }

    private function fullQuery($hostname, $port=25565)
    {
        $sessionId = $this->makeSessionId();

        $fp = stream_socket_client('udp://' . $hostname . ':' . $port);
        if (!$fp) {
            return false;
        }

        $time = microtime(true);

        $challengeToken = $this->handleQueryHandshake($fp, $sessionId);
        if (!$challengeToken) {
            fclose($fp);
            return false;
        }

        $time = round((microtime(true)-$time)*1000);

        $statRequest = pack('cccNNN', 0xFE, 0xFD, 0, $sessionId, $challengeToken, 0);
        fwrite($fp, $statRequest);
        $statResponseHeader = fread($fp, 5);

        if (!$this->validateQueryResponse($statResponseHeader, 0, $sessionId)) {
            fclose($fp);
            return false;
        }

        fread($fp, 11);

        // Should only encounter double null thrice.
        while ($doubleNulsEncountered < 3) {
            $c = fread($fp, 1);
            $statResponse .= $c;

            if ($lastWasNul && $c === chr(0)) {
                $doubleNulsEncountered++;
            }

            $lastWasNul = ($c === chr(0));
        }

        fclose($fp);

        $statResponseData = explode(pack('cccccccccccc', 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x70, 0x6C, 0x61,
                                         0x79, 0x65, 0x72, 0x5F, 0x00, 0x00), $statResponse);
        foreach (explode(chr(0), $statResponseData[0]) as $index => $item) {
            if (!($index % 2)) {
                switch ($item) {
                case 'numplayers':
                    $key = 'player_count';
                    break;
                case 'maxplayers':
                    $key = 'player_max';
                    break;
                case 'hostname':
                    $key = 'motd';
                    break;
                case 'hostip':
                    $key = 'ip';
                    break;
                case 'hostport':
                    $key = 'port';
                    break;
                default:
                    $key = $item;
                    break;
                }
            } else {
                if ($key == 'port') {
                    $item = (string)$item;
                }
                $stats[$key] = $item;
            }
        }

        $stats['latency'] = $time;

        $players = explode(chr(0), $statResponseData[1]);
        array_pop($players);

        $stats['players'] = $players;
        return $stats;
    }
}

// ============================================================

if (!count(debug_backtrace())) {
    $args = array_slice($argv, 1);
    foreach ($args as $arg) {
        $e = explode(':', $arg, 1);
        $len = count($e);
        if ($len > 2 || $len < 1) {
            print('Invalid host '.$arg);
            exit(1);
        } elseif ($len == 1) {
            $e[1] = 25565;
        }
        $m = new MinecraftStatus($e[0], $e[1]);
        $reply = $m->ping();
        $motd = preg_replace("/(\\x{00A7}.|\n)/u", '', $reply['motd']);
        $message = $e[0].':'.$e[1].' '.$motd.' ';
        $message .= $reply['player_count'].'/'.$reply['player_max']. ' ';
        $message .= $reply['latency'].'ms'."\n";
        print($message);
    }
}

?>
```

### minecraft_users.php

Stand-alone [Munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/) plugin.

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

/*
  ===============
  minecraft_users
  ===============

  This is munin plugin to monitor the player count on a Minecraft server.
  Install it like any other munin plugin:
  # cp minecraft_users.php /usr/share/munin/plugins/minecraft_users
  # chmod 755 /usr/share/munin/plugins/minecraft_users
  # ln -s /usr/share/munin/plugins/minecraft_users /etc/munin/plugins/minecraft_users

  Config:
  [minecraft_users]
  env.host aminecraftserver.org
  env.port 25565
 */

error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);

$host = getenv('host');
$host = $host ? $host : 'localhost';

$port = getenv('port');
$port = $port ? $port : '25565';

if ((count($argv) > 1) && ($argv[1] == 'config')) {
    print("graph_title Connected players\n");
    print("graph_vlabel players\n");
    print("players.label Number of players\n");
    print("max_players.label Max players\n");
    print("graph_info Number of players connected to Minecraft\n");
    print("graph_scale no\n");
    print("graph_category minecraft\n");
    exit();
}

/*
  ================
  Server List Ping
  ================

  An example of how to get a Minecraft server status's using a "Server List Ping" packet.
  See details here: http://www.wiki.vg/Server_List_Ping
*/

function MC_packString($string)
{
    return pack('n', strlen($string)) . mb_convert_encoding($string, 'UCS-2BE');
}

// This is needed since UCS-2 text rendered as UTF-8 contains unnecessary null bytes
// and could cause other components, especially string functions to blow up. Boom!
function MC_decodeUCS2BE($string)
{
    return mb_convert_encoding($string, 'UTF-8', 'UCS-2BE');
}

function MC_serverListPing($hostname, $port=25565)
{
    // 1. pack data to send
    $request = pack('nc', 0xfe01, 0xfa) .
        MC_packString('MC|PingHost') .
        pack('nc', 7+2*strlen($hostname), 73) .
        MC_packString($hostname) .
        pack('N', 25565);

    // 2. open communication socket and make transaction
    $time = microtime(true);
    $fp = stream_socket_client('tcp://' . $hostname . ':' . $port);
    if (!$fp) {
        return false;
    }
    fwrite($fp, $request);
    $response = fread($fp, 2048);
    fclose($fp);
    $time = round((microtime(true)-$time)*1000);

    // 3. unpack data and return
    if (strpos($response, 0xFF) !== 0) {
        return false;
    }
    $response = substr($response, 3);
    $response = explode(pack('n', 0), $response);

    return array(
                'player_count' => MC_decodeUCS2BE($response[4]),
                'player_max' => MC_decodeUCS2BE($response[5]),
                'motd' => MC_decodeUCS2BE($response[3]),
                'server_version' => MC_decodeUCS2BE($response[2]),
                'protocol_version' => MC_decodeUCS2BE($response[1]),
                'latency' => $time
                );
}

// ============================================================

$reply = MC_serverListPing($host, $port);

print('players.value ' . $reply['player_count'] . "\n");
print('max_players.value ' . $reply['player_max'] . "\n");
?>
```

### stat.php

Basic webpage to check Minecraft server status.

```
<?php

require_once './mcstat.php';
require_once './mcformat.php';

$hostname = NULL;
if (array_key_exists('server', $_GET)) {
    $hostname = $_GET['server'];
}

if ($hostname) {
    $m = new MinecraftStatus($hostname);
    $status = $m->ping();
}

$hostname = htmlspecialchars($hostname);

echo '
<html>
<head>
<style>
.motd {
text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000;
        filter: dropshadow(color=#000000, offx=1, offy=1);
}
</style>';

echo '<title> Minecraft Server Status' . ($hostname ? ' :: ' . $hostname : '') . '</title>';

echo '</head>
<body>
<p>Query server status:</p>
<form name="MC" method="get" action="">
<input type="text" name="server" onClick="this.select();" value="'.($hostname ? $hostname : '').'">
<input type="submit">
</form>';

if ($hostname) {
    echo '<h1>Status for ' . $hostname . '</h1>';
    if ($status) {
        echo '<table>
<tr><th>MOTD</th><th>Server version</th><th>Players</th><th>Ping</th></tr>';
        echo '<tr><td class="motd">' . MC_parseMotdColors($status['motd']). '</td><td>' .
            $status['server_version'] . '</td><td>' . $status['player_count'] .
            '/' . $status['player_max'] . '</td><td>' . $status['latency'] . '</td></tr>';
        echo '</table>';
    } else {
        echo '<p>Could not query server.</p>';
    }
}

echo '</body>
</html>';

?>
```

### mcformat.php

HTML formatter for [Minecraft chat color escapes](http://wiki.vg/Chat#Control_Sequences).

```
<?php

// Multibyte str_split()
function MC_str_split( $string )
{
    return preg_split('/(?<!^)(?!$)/u', $string );
}

// http://www.wiki.vg/Chat
function MC_parseMotdColors($motd)
{
    $inColorSequence = false;
    $openSpan = false;
    $coloredMotd = '';

    foreach (MC_str_split($motd) as $character) {
        if ($inColorSequence) {

            // find color and insert span
            switch ($character) {
            case '0':
                $color = '#000000';
                break;
            case '1':
                $color = '#0000aa';
                break;
            case '2':
                $color = '#00aa00';
                break;
            case '3':
                $color = '#00aaaa';
                break;
            case '4':
                $color = '#aa0000';
                break;
            case '5':
                $color = '#aa00aa';
                break;
            case '6':
                $color = '#ffaa00';
                break;
            case '7':
                $color = '#aaaaaa';
                break;
            case '8':
                $color = '#555555';
                break;
            case '9':
                $color = '#5555ff';
                break;
            case 'a':
                $color = '#55ff55';
                break;
            case 'b':
                $color = '#55ffff';
                break;
            case 'c':
                $color = '#ff5555';
                break;
            case 'd':
                $color = '#ff55ff';
                break;
            case 'e':
                $color = '#ffff55';
                break;
            case 'f':
            case 'r':
                $color = '#ffffff';
                break;
            default:
                $color = false;
                break;
            }

            if ($color) {
                if ($openSpan) {
                    $coloredMotd .= '</span>';
                }

                $coloredMotd .= '<span style="color:' . $color . ';">';
                $openSpan = true;
            }

            $inColorSequence = false;
        } elseif ($character== '§') {
            $inColorSequence = true;
        } else {
            $coloredMotd .= $character;
        }
    }

    if ($openSpan) {
        $coloredMotd .= '</span>';
    }

    return $coloredMotd;
}

?>
```

## Information on Minecraft's Protocols

If you want to learn more about getting information from [Minecraft](https://minecraft.net), see this [article on Server List Ping](http://wiki.vg/Server_List_Ping) and [this on the Query protocol](http://wiki.vg/Query).

If you're looking for a server to test my code with, try [Uberminecraft.com](http://Uberminecraft.com).

Comment: Looks fairly concise, I would maybe `FILTER` your `GETs` though using PHP's `filter_input` function `$foo = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'foo', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);`

Comment: Hello. I'm using https://github.com/xPaw/PHP-Minecraft-Query solution

I got some issue with response HostName:

    ?8?m-]?5?m--?2?l ?b?l+!6?c?l7/2,$ ?5?m--?8?m[-?c ?f?lKavBuy.Ru ?e?l1.8-1.10 ?b?l?e?lSurvival?b?l?b,?a?lMarry?b?l?b,?b?lSkyWars,?c?lClans?b?l?b,?f?lParkour

How to convert it into human view?

Comment: @Adobe you're better off asking at https://github.com/xPaw/PHP-Minecraft-Query/issues

Answer (score 3):

### Foreword

Bearing in mind that this post was created more than 4 years ago, you likely have changed the code and learned more about PHP features - perhaps you don't even use/maintain this code anymore. I honestly have never played Minecraft, nor had any reason to monitor server statuses. But I wanted to give some feedback to this question.

### Feedback

The code looks pretty sophisticated. I honestly haven't used `pack()` before. That is neat that the class `MinecraftStatus` can function as a stand-alone CLI tool.

### Suggestions

#### Utilize member variable instead of passing

The methods `MinecraftStatus::ping()` and `MinecraftStatus::query()` make calls to private methods like `serverListPing()`, `basicQuery()` and `fullQuery()`, which all appear to be private methods. Instead of passing the hostname and portnumber to those methods, the methods can utilize the member variables using `$this->`. That way, the member variables don't need to be passed around.

#### Mapping Character to colors

The `switch` statement in `MC_parseMotdColors()` could be replaced by a lookup in an array.

```
define('COLOR_MAPPING', [
    '0' => '000000',
    '1' => '0000aa',
    //2-9, a-e...
    'f' => 'ffffff',
    'r' => 'ffffff'
]);
```

Then lookup the value of `$character` using [`array_key_exists()`](http://array_key_exists):

```
$color = false; //default value
if (array_key_exists($character, COLOR_MAPPING)) {
    $color = '#' . COLOR_MAPPING[$character];
}
```

The same is true for the `switch` statement within `MinecraftStatus::fullQuery()` - though instead of using `define()`, a class constant could be created using `const`:

```
const RESPONSE_ITEM_KEY_MAPPING = [
    'numplayers' => 'player_count',
    'maxplayers' => 'player_max',
    'hostname' => 'motd',
    'hostip' => 'ip',
    'hostport' => 'port',
];
```

and then that constant can be accessed using `self::RESPONSE_ITEM_KEY_MAPPING`.

```
$key = $item; //default value
if (array_key_exists($item, self::RESPONSE_ITEM_KEY_MAPPING)) {
    $key = self::RESPONSE_ITEM_KEY_MAPPING[$item];
}
```

#### Alternatives to `fwrite()`, `fread()`, `fclose()`

I am not sure if it would work but you could consider using [cURL wrapper functions](http://php.net/curl) or [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/file_get_contents) - that way the parsing of individual characters could possibly be eliminated.

#### Reading characters in `getStrings()`

I haven't tested it but in theory the (outer) `while` loop could be simplified to a `for` loop:

```
for ($nulsProcessed = 0; $nulsProcessed < $count; $nulsProcessed++) {
    while ($c != chr(0)) {
        $s .= $c;
        $c = fread($fp, 1);
    }
    $strings[] = $s;
    unset($c);
    unset($s);
})
```

And also the nested `while` could also be rewritten as a `for` loop:

```
while($c = fread($fp, 1); $c != char(0); $c = fread($fp, 1)) {
    $s .= $c;
}
```